# Session does not work in custom action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I have an ASP.NET custom action filter:

```
namespace Sample.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class SampleValidator : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override Task OnActionExecutingAsync(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var tokenValidated = HttpContext.Current.Session["TokenValidated"];
            if (tokenValidated == null || tokenValidated != "true")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["TokenValidated"] = "true";
            }

            return base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

However, HttpContextFactory.Current.Session is NULL.  I need to store cross-request state information in the session in this custom attribute.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If session doesn't work in the filter, there are several methods that can be used to store your global variables such as cookie and static variable.

try this:

```
public static Boolean TokenValidated {get; set;}
```

You can set TokenValidated directly anywhere in your code such as :

```
TokenValidated = true;
```

Also you can get TokenValidated anywhere in your code.

Comment: That static would make it a global state; don't want that.  Need a per user setting.

Comment: Try use cookie. Do you know how to use cookie ?

Comment: If you do not know iI will update the answer to show how to use cookie

Comment: I up-voted your answer because we ended up using a combination secured cookies and custom headers so as to keep the web api restful.  Did not accept it as an answer since it did not really answered my question.

Comment: Thanks webtecki. The good news is that you solve your problem. I am happy for you.